# Edit VersionInfo of a file using powershell

Tags: powershell, file-attributes

I would like to use empty fields in a files VersionInfo to store meta data for search purposes. I would like to know if it's possible to edit the VersionInfo fields using a powershell cmdlet or script.

The VersionInfo can be viewed using the following command:

```
get-itemproperty -path .\amazon_cel_v2l.dvf | Format-List -Property VersionInfo
```

output:

```
VersionInfo : File:             C:\extended_attributes\amazon_cel_v2l.dvf
              InternalName:
              OriginalFilename:
              FileVersion:
              FileDescription:
              Product:
              ProductVersion:
              Debug:            False
              Patched:          False
              PreRelease:       False
              PrivateBuild:     False
              SpecialBuild:     False
              Language:
```

As you can see there are several different empty fields that could be populated with metadata. Does anyone know if/how these fields can be written to? In particular I would like to use the four fields listed below:

```
              InternalName:
              OriginalFilename:
              FileVersion:
              FileDescription:
```

Comment: IIRC, this is (generally) only possible by rebuilding the executable with updated version information.

Comment: Yeah, this information is only set on executables and libraries.  The properties are read-only from .Net.  There's more information at [the FileVersionInfo class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo?view=netframework-4.7.2): "The FileVersionInfo properties are based on version resource information built into the file. Version resources are often built into binary files such as .exe or .dll files; text files do not have version resource information."  Whatever you're trying to do, these properties are probably not the way to do it.

Comment: I would add that editing such metadata in a signed executable would invalidate the signature. I agree with Bacon Bits that you probably need to think a different way about whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments in my question, I am going to try to come up with a different way to add custom meta data to my files. Alternate Data Streams are good but are lost if a file is transferred to a non-ntfs file system.